# Использование java-сервлета и аннотаций

Tags: java, apache, jsp, servlet, аннотации

Здравствуйте, нужна Ваша посильная помощь, мой первый проект на эту тему, и появились трудности. Суть в чём, установил jre1.8.0_66, установил apache v9, установил eclipse, создал проект Dynamic Web Project, добавил в classpath для проекта jar-ку с servlet-api-3.1.0, которую требовали импорты сервлета authorization.java, автоматически созданные после его создания пкм->new->Servlet, ошибки ушли, дальше создал страничку jsp (login.jsp) на которой есть простейшая форма отпраки логина и пароля:

***login.jsp***

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Авторизация</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="authorization" method="get">
        Пользователь:
        <input name="login">
        Пароль:
        <input nam="password">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

как в видеоуроках в интернете, я сделал сервлет, которому дописал аннотацию, по которой будет доступно обращаться к классу сервлета и использовать метод doGet:

***authorization.java***

```
package servlet;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet("/authorization")
public class authorization extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public authorization() {
        super();
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("doGet");
    }
}
```

но, при отправке данных (нажатием на отправить форму) у меня не находит мой сервлет [image: пример ошибки 1]

структура проекта:

[image: структура проекта]

смотрел как это делается вот тут: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l9EYJnsJWBc&list=PLwcDaxeEINad0vuk7vVxlWLrVI-Y5UK3H&index=6

но не получается как у него, не работает, может подскажете место где я мог прошляпиться, что я делаю не так? при учёте что хочется это сделать через аннотации, как там, не используя маппинги и прочее в web.xml т.к. у него ведь и без этого работает

содержимое web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="registry" version="3.1">
  <display-name>registry</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Comment: добавьте содержимое web.xml в вопрос

Comment: исправил, добавил

Comment: В консоль ТС точно не выводится фраза "doGet"? Потому что вывод в консоль и в ответ сервлета - разные вещи. Под дебагом пробовали?

Comment: точно, в консоли не отрабатывает это http://jpegshare.net/images/04/9d/049d7949f7e115899a99dcd66d4e1410.jpg

Comment: 1)Не вижу маппинга вашего сервлета в web.xml 2) Что такое /registry... пакет в котором лежит ваш класс authorization?

Comment: 1) маппинги как сказано не нужно описывать в web.xml при использовании аннотаций это же сказано ещё и тут: http://devcolibri.com/4284

Comment: 2) registry это название самого проекта, и всё

Comment: Только что повторил Ваш проект 1 в 1. за исключением того, что у меня NetBeans. Строка doGet выводится в консоль сервера tomcat.

Comment: Попробуйте подключить себе javaee-web-api-7.0.jar

Comment: Если хотите могу запаковать и сбросить вам то, что у меня получилось(Сборка на maven, если у вас он в Eclipse настроен)

Comment: попробовал подключить себе web-api-7.0 - не помогло, тоже самое, если не трудно, сбросьте

Comment: Попробуй в форме, которая находится в jsp изменить action на "/authorization"

Answer (score 1):

попробуйте так

```
package servlet;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet(
        name = "LoginUser",
        description = "Вход пользователя - проверка имени пользователя и пароля",
        urlPatterns = "/LoginUser"
)

public class authorization extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public authorization() {
        super();
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("doGet");
    }

        protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
                          HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        String login = request.getParameter("login");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");                           
                          }
}
```